# Javascript not triggered at the end of the page

Tags: javascript, scroll

I'm trying to trigger an alert at the end of the page below, but it keeps triggering as soon as I scroll. I've tried a few different methods, but each time the alert is triggered before the bottom of the page.
Missing from the code is just a DB call that triggers about 20 results, the header and a php include that displays the results. The displayed results show about 4 screens worth of data.

```
<body>
    <div class="maincontainer">
        <div class="profilecontainer">
            <row>
                <column cols="4" class="left">
                    This will have text
                </column>
                <column cols="8" class="right">
                    <ul class="post-column">
                        <?php 
                        foreach ($data as $lineitem):
                        $type = $lineitem['type'];
                        if($type == "article"){
                           require('php/articleitem.php');
                        }

                        endforeach; 
                        ?>
                    </ul>
                </column>
            </row>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>

<script>
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(document).height() <= $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) {
            alert("End Of The Page");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

when `window.innerHeight + document.body.scrollTop` is greater than or equal to `document.body.offsetHeight` then you are at bottom

Answer (score 0):

The result of `$(window).height()` will not be as expected when you don't have a document type at the top of your HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Add it, and you will no longer get the alert too soon.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to set the following css values.

```
.body {
   position: absolute;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: With the code you supplied in the question, this does not resolve the issue. I was able to still reproduce your problem with this CSS included... To fix it correctly you have to define a doc type, which [is a required part of any document in the HTML syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#doctype-syntax)